# How to find migrations of external installed django apps?

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, migration

Given: a number of external Django apps that I use in INSTALLED_APPS.

What I want to:
perform makemigrations

What I get:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration users.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions')
```

Question: how to set up consistent migrations with actual schema state? So I could just run makemigrations and migrate without manually tuning db each time

Comment: What do you mean by "_restore the whole db_"? Please be more clear and specific. What _exactly_ do you want to do?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat could you have a look again? a bit changed desc

Comment: I believe you developed on a version of Django>=2.2 but you are trying to run it on a version Django<2.2 which is why you get the error. (Ever heard of `pip freeze > requirements.txt`? If not do check that out and also how to install packages from the so generated requirements file)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I scarcely believe it could be the case. Of course I am aware of it and developed under the same version. But what is interesting, where I could find these migration files, corresponding to the installed apps. So I have these migration files in my apps but struggling find these from others. Thank you!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat in my requierements file I have django>=3.2.3